# How to I make tapping anywhere outside of the TextField make it loose focus?

Tags: flutter

When I tap on a `TextField` it gains focus. The keyboard opens and typing works. Now I'm done typing and I tap anywhere except the`TextField`, I expected the focus to change and the keyboard to go away, it doesn't.

How to I make tapping anywhere outside of the `TextField` make it loose focus?

Comment: or you can use this package :) https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Answer (score 13):

You can use `onTapOutside` parameter of the [`TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/TextField.html).

```dart
TextField(
    onTapOutside: (event) {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }
),
```

Comment: why does this not work when switching textfield? i'm running another function, not trying to unfocus

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the whole screen in `GestureDetector` so that when  you touch anywhere on `GestureDetector`, `onTap` method is called which will hide the soft keyboard.

```
new Scaffold(
  body: new GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      /*This method here will hide the soft keyboard.*/
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    },
    child: new Container(
       //More work here
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution for general Touch-Events

To collapse the keyboard on interactions outside the focused widget, wrap that part with a `Listener` and call `unfocus()` on the current FocusScope from its `onPointerDown` callback.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (event) {
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  },
  child: ...
),
```

Here, I'm using `Listener` instead of a `GestureDetector` as it will trigger the callback for any touch interactions and not just on tap which is usually the expected behavior for focus management.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this function, 

final _emailFocus = FocusNode();
 final _passwordFocus = FocusNode();
```

final _emailController = TextEditingController();

```
child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              focusNode: _emailFocus,
              onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
              _emailFocus.unfocus();
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocus);
              },
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to un focus Textfield  with below code:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (term){
  currentNode.unfocus();
}
```